# Как очистить boolean переменную после обновления приложения но только раз?

Tags: java, android

Задача следующая при открытии приложения  нужно вывести  окно с информацией о версии приложения . В окне я нажму ок и окно больше не будет  показывалось.  Но при обновлении приложения мне снова нужно вывести это окно как сбросить AlertState_Info_text в false  .

Беда в том что что если сбросить  AlertState_Info_text в false при открытии приложения оно всегда будет сбрасывать переменную   тем самым всегда будет показывать окно. (Нужно чтобы сбросило при обновлении и больше не трогало.)

Сорян если чё объяснил как мог

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Info_text", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean AlertState_Info_text = prefs.getBoolean("Info_text", Info_text);

        if (AlertState_Info_text == false) {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.AlertState_Info_text_Title)
                    .setMessage(R.string.AlertState_Info_text_Message)


                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                            Info_text = true;
                            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = getSharedPreferences("Info_text", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            ed.putBoolean("Info_text", Info_text);
                            ed.commit();

                        }
                    })

                    .create().show();
```

Comment: Используйте переменную в sharedpreference, и привяжите её смену лучше к версии приложения. Так надёжнее и вернее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас по условию 2 параметра, отвечающие за показ диалога. А вы в логике используете только одно. Добавьте ещё и проверку версии. Или даже оставьте только проверку версии. Типа как-то так (псевдо-код):

```
if (Build.VERSION_CODE != preferences.getInt("lastShownVersion", 0)) {
   //показываем диалог, по закрытию диалога обновляем версию в префах по ключу lastShownVersion на текущую (взятую из Build.VERSION_CODE)
} else {
   // ничего не делаем.
}
```